# MS access - count function

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to count number of rows in my complex query (this query is designed to meet my requirement). The result should be, e.g. NumberOfRecord: 10. However, I am not getting the result I am expecting. How do I improve my query? Thanks

### My query:

[image]>

### Result:

http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/6414/222222o.png

The MS Access SQL view:

```
SELECT Count(tblMeeting.Meeting_Id) AS [Number of jobs]
FROM (tblEmployee INNER JOIN tblMeetingType ON tblEmployee.Emp_Id = tblMeetingType.Chairperson_Id) INNER JOIN tblMeeting ON tblMeetingType.Type_Id = tblMeeting.Type_Id
GROUP BY tblMeeting.MeetingDate, tblMeeting.AgendaApproved, tblMeeting.AgendaTopic
HAVING (((tblMeeting.MeetingDate)>DateAdd("d",3,Now())) AND ((tblMeeting.AgendaApproved)=False) AND ((tblMeeting.AgendaTopic) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: Are you expecting a single result row? If so, I am not sure I understand the GROUP BY for this query. My guess is to remove the GROUP BY and change HAVING to WHERE.

Comment: Try changing the `groupby` part of the query editor to `where` where you are not using the information i.e. meetig date, agenda approved, agenda topic

Comment: Yes, the result should be only one row showing the total number of rows. Thanks

Comment: Also I can't see why you are bothering with a join you could just count the id of `tblMeeting` with the same criteria as the information from the other tables are unused.

Comment: Tom, because I will use the UserName as a session variable in my ASP.NET application.

Comment: Thanks guys, I finally solved my problem. I have removed GROUP BY to WHERE.

Comment: You can better provide your solution as an answer and accept it. That is legal on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, I finally solved my problem.

I have changed GROUP BY to WHERE.

The query should look like this:

http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/628/solutionl.png